# Magento 2: How to call Email template in email templates?

Tags: magento-2.1, email-templates

Is it possible to call email template in another email templates like we do for the header and footer

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
```

Maybe via template ID or we have to use Custom Variables and CMS blocks?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below to achieve this.

1. Create config.xml and add config with template id you want to use.
   `<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
   <default>
       <design>
           <email>
               <custom_template>design_email_custom_template</custom_template>
           </email>
       </design>
   </default>
   </config>`
2. Inside the template use this value as config path.

`{{template config_path="design/email/custom_template"}}`